# How do I install the Travis Client on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, ruby

Im'm trying to install this:

[Travis client](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb)

by doing `sudo gem install travis`
but I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing travis:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170310-8171-xumwrs.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out
```

How do I remove what I installed and install it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced a similar problem when I was trying to install travis. `ruby-dev` was not installed in my system. I reran the command to install travis after installing `ruby-dev`.

I installed `ruby-dev` using the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

I referred to this answer. Hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304438/gem-install-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cant-find-header-files

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have ruby. ruby --version
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Comment: @M.Becerra Thank you. I have edited the answer. Pardon me. I am a noob to StackExchange. I will keep that in mind from now on. :)

Comment: @lapisdecor I am sorry. I also have the same version. I don't know why it is still giving error.

Comment: You mean ruby-dev not ruby, I just edited your answer to become more clear.